# Creating method with reference to a class

Tags: c#

Forgive me for strange title, however I had huge problem with proper naming.

I'm facing a problem with the `LoginPage` class:

```
public class LoginPage : PageBase
{
    private static readonly By IsLoadedLocator = By.Id("logo");

    public LoginPage(IWebDriver webDriver) : base(webDriver)
    {
        if (!IsLoaded()) throw new NoSuchElementException("Login page is not loaded");
    }

    // (1) This method
    public LoginFormComponent GetLoginFormComponent()
    {
        var component = new LoginFormComponent(this);
        return component.IsLoaded() ? component : null;
    }

    public override By GetIsLoadedLocator()
    {
        return IsLoadedLocator;
    }
}
```

The method marked with (1). What exactly is happening here, `LoginFormComponent` is a class. We're creating method based on the different class, what's the purpose of doing something like this?

**Second Question**

```
var loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
```

Where loginPage is variable, we're initializing an object but why it's not done in normal way like:

```
LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver)
```

Comment: There is no difference between `var loginPage = new LoginPage(...)` and `LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(...)`, the `var` is just a shortcut saying "figure it out from what I put on the right side".

Comment: This is called implicit declaration, when you are using VAR, the variable gets its type when it is assigned. And it should be assigned when you use var. E.g. var i; is not possible, but var i = 0; is OK

Comment: Please try to ask one question per 'question'.  To understand the reasoning why, please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post

Comment: Your second question is easily Google-able, we're happy to help you but you should maybe try a little harder with your research before coming here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question:

```
public LoginFormComponent GetLoginFormComponent()
{
    var component = new LoginFormComponent(this);
    return component.IsLoaded() ? component : null;
}
```

`GetLoginFormComponent()` is a method that returns something that is a `LoginFormComponent`.  The first line of the method is creating a new instance of `LoginFormComponent` and passing the very instance of `LoginPage` that you are currently in (by using `this`).  The second line is using the [ternary operator `?:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) which basically says if the first expression is true, return the item after the `?`, if the expression is false return the item after the `:`.  It can also be written as:

```
if(component.IsLoaded())
{
    return component;
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

As for your second question, `var` is just a sort of syntactic sugar to prevent a programmer from writing redundant code.  Look at the traditional way of declaring a variable and instantiating it:

```
LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
```

It is sorta redundant right?  Why did we need to type `LoginPage` twice?  When you use `var` the compiler will determine the type implicitly (to save you from writing redundant code):

```
var loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
```

Keep in mind though that `var` is not the same as a JavaScript `var`.  `var` is not a loosely typed object, it's just a short hand for programmers.

Comment: I don't see how putting actual data type in-front of the declaration is 'redundant code'. PS. I didn't down-vote, however your answer does not differ from mine except for teaching how to use ternary operator.

Comment: @Adriani6 in the case of `LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);` it is.  There is no need to type it twice since the type is apparent just by looking at the initialization.  However, scenarios like: `var someObj = someService.GetObject();` I think using the explicit type is preferred because it is not immediately obvious what the type is.  Also, your answer was fine, I just wanted to touch on `this` and the ternary operator since I wasnt sure what part OP was confused on.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer Sir... You said that this is a method that returns something from LoginFormComponent class. I can't really understand that, we're involving class in a method of different class to let that class create/ initialize object??

Comment: @Ixi11 I am a bit confused by your comment.  The method is just returning an instance of `LoginFormComponent`.  C# is an object oriented language, you will be doing a lot with objects/classes which will include returning objects created from other classes.  This is pretty commonplace in C#

Comment: @Ixi11 its ok, its hard to even know how to ask the questions when you are first starting out.  I think it would help a lot if you went through some some tutorials on classes/objects in C#.  Might help you get a greater understanding to that aspect

Answer (score 0):

First question:

```
public LoginFormComponent GetLoginFormComponent()
{
   // Create an instance of LoginFormComponent
   var component = new LoginFormComponent(this);
   // Return component if IsLoaded == true or null if it's false.
   return component.IsLoaded() ? component : null;
}
```

Second question:

The keyword `var` is like a placeholder for a variable type, upon compilation of the code, the compiler will 'behind the scenes' determine and replace var with appropriate data type.

`var` is not to be mixed with `dynamic` though, as they are different.